# Speaker label/ diarization does not return in Watson Speech to Text API

Tags: python, api, speech-recognition, ibm-watson

I am trying to get speaker labels through IBM watson speech to text api.
In my final output I want it to display the transcript, the confidence and the speaker labels for the entire audio. My code is below:

```
import json
from os.path import join, dirname
from ibm_watson import SpeechToTextV1
from ibm_watson.websocket import RecognizeCallback, AudioSource
import threading
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator
import pandas as pd
authenticator = IAMAuthenticator('rXXXYYZZ')
service = SpeechToTextV1(authenticator=authenticator)
service.set_service_url('https://api.us-east.speech-to-text.watson.cloud.ibm.com')

models = service.list_models().get_result()
#print(json.dumps(models, indent=2))

model = service.get_model('en-US_BroadbandModel').get_result()
#print(json.dumps(model, indent=2))

with open(join(dirname('__file__'), 'testvoicejen.wav'),
          'rb') as audio_file:
#    print(json.dumps(
    output = service.recognize(
    audio=audio_file,
    speaker_labels=True,
    content_type='audio/wav',
    #timestamps=True,
    #word_confidence=True,
    model='en-US_NarrowbandModel',
    continuous=True).get_result(),
    indent=2
df = pd.DataFrame([i for elts in output for alts in elts['results'] for i in alts['alternatives']])
```

However, the output of df is:

```
df
Out[22]: 
                                          timestamps  ...                                         transcript
0  [[thank, 3.88, 4.04], [you, 4.04, 4.13], [for,...  ...  thank you for calling my name is Britney and h...
1  [[thank, 30.21, 30.56], [you, 30.56, 30.74], [...  ...  thank you %HESITATION and then %HESITATION you..
```

As you can observe, I do get the transcript successfully, however, instead of speaker diarization or labels, I get timestamps. A speaker label would be something like the below:

```
from": 0.68,
      "to": 1.19,
      "speaker": 2
```

How do I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you switch on `speaker_labels` you get `timestamps` automatically. If you take a look at the sample output in the service documentation - https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/speech-to-text?topic=speech-to-text-output#speaker_labels

You will see that the speaker labels section is separate from the alternatives / results section. Your code only parses the results / alternatives section. To get the speaker labels you need something like -

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([i for elts in output for i in elts['speaker_labels']])
```